# Where can I get a ARMv 8.5 device for some academic experiments

Tags: arm, embedded

I am very interested in the memory tagging feature enabled by ARM v8.5. However, I just have no idea from where I can get a device enabled this very new feature. Could anyone shed some lights on this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Questions asking where to find off-site resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is any easily available silicon implementing v8.5 for the time being, I would rather suggest experimenting with the [Armv8-A Base Platform FVP](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/simulation-models/fixed-virtual-platforms): it does support version 8.5.